# How to access object.prototype methods from another file using module.exports?

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I want to use an object and its methods in another file, how would I set up my module.exports?

Object:

```
var Object = function ()
{ 
...
}

Object.prototype.foo = function (param)
{
...
}
```

Module.export:

```
module.exports = {
    Object : Object
}
```

or

```
module.exports = {
    Object : Object,
    foo : Object.prototype.foo
}
```

?

Comment: don't override `Object`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few ways of doing this but if you're trying to access prototype methods from your other file, then you'll need to instantiate your constructor, 
something like:

For ex:

```
// lib.js

var YourThing = function () {
}

YourThing.prototype.someMethod = function () {
  console.log('do something cool');
}

module.exports = YourThing;

// index.js

var YT = require('./lib.js');
var yourThing = new YT();
yourThing.someMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = Object;
```

This will export your Object as a Module.

Comment: Would I be able to access all of its methods? Also, how would I call this object in the other file? 
`var obj = require('./file.js')` and `var instance = new obj.Object()`?

Answer (score 0):

If your object is not renewed in your app, the best way to use it as an executed function with late binding of its prototype methods

```
const _ = require('lodash')
var Object = function ()
{ 
    ..
    _.bindAll(this); // at last bind all methods. this way you won't miss a method
}

Object.prototype.foo = function (param)
{
     ...
}

module.exports = new Object();
```

then you can call the functions like,

```
const myObj = require('./object-file')
myObj.myMethod();
```

If you need reusable component,

```
module.exports = Object;

const _obj = require('./object-file'); // you can call this way anywhere in any function and for every require, it creates a new object.
var object = new _obj();
_obj.anyMethod();
```