# Accessing prototype function from node modules

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to implement `3rd party rest API` in `php` project for integrating another project which is in `angular`.

Using `rest API`, I need to store `cookie` in the browser and `cookie value` will be in a specific format as instructed for which I need to import a specific `npm package` called `angular2-cookie` inside my `root directory` from

https://github.com/salemdar/angular2-cookie/blob/master/src/services/cookies.service.ts

I successfully installed it using `npm command` inside `root directory`.

In **/js/sample-script.js**

I imported the specific `cookies.service.js` file from that `angular2-cookie module` using `browserify lib` like

```
var CookieService = require('../node_modules/angular2-cookie/services/cookies.service');

var cs = new CookieService();
cs.putObject('somecookie',{user: 'john'});
```

but in the console, I am getting an error like:

> Uncaught TypeError: CookieService is not a constructor

How can I  implement `putObject` method from `CookieService prototype`?

**Note:** There is no error coming till 1st line where I used `require` method

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49063413/how-to-access-object-prototype-methods-from-another-file-using-module-exports

Comment: already tried like that

Comment: Okie, I'll to check on the same

Comment: @HiranyaSarma usage of the library is all documented in the README of the library, the code example you have given doesn't follow any of that. FWIW the library you are using is now deprecated.

Comment: can u little elaborate,what was not followed?

Comment: @HiranyaSarma have you configured the system JS as per the [docs](https://github.com/salemdar/angular2-cookie#installation)? Also, given this is a module, you don't need to directly reference the `node_modules` folder in your path.